# Question on set theory and first order logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I need help with this problem on set theory.

For any sets $A$ and $B$, consider the set $S$ defined below:

$$S = \{ x \mid \neg (x ∈ A \to x ∈ B) \}$$

I need to write an expression for $S$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ using the standard set operators (union, intersection, etc.)

Comment: Jose: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: Hi Martin, I wasn't aware.  Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @m0nhawk If you wonder why your suggested edit [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/84651) has been rejected, have a look at [this post at meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/editing-to-remove-a-thank-you-in-a-post). (I've posted a comment here, since I don't think the ping would have reached you in the thread with rejected edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
$$p\to q \iff \lnot p\lor q$$
and
$$\{x\mid x\in A \land x\in B\}=A\cap B$$
$$\{x\mid x\in A \lor x\in B\}=A\cup B$$
$$\{x\mid x\in  \lnot(x\in A)\}=A^C$$
where $A^C$ is complement of $A$.

Comment: So would this be: $S = x ∈ (A ∩ ¬ B)$?

Comment: @Jose Yes, you are right.

Comment: are you sure? I'm doubtful I got it correct on the first try haha.

Comment: I'm sure that your answer is correct.